# If an alpha particle is emitted during an alpha decay, why do some people call it radiation?

Tags: particle-physics, terminology, radiation

I wonder if there is some dual nature here similar to that of light. That would be confusing for me since the alpha particle is made out of protons and neutrons. Tell me please what I am getting wrong.

Comment: [Radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation) does not have to refer to *"electro-magnetic"* radiation, it can also refer to particles.

Comment: Dual nature indeed: particle-wave duality. Originally referred to as $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ radiation, they turned out to be helium nuclei, electrons and photons resp. You are not getting anything wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Radiation in this context refers to radioactivity which simply means energy is transmitted from an unstable nucleus. The form of energy transfer may happen in forms of particles (such as alpha) or photons (gamma).

The terms alpha, beta and gamma originated at a time when sub-atomic structure was not properly understood. Thus different particles which came out of an radioactive decay were simply named alpha, beta, gamma or x-ray. Now we know an alpha particle is merely made of protons and neutrons. Beta simply mean highly energetic electron and gamma is highly energetic photon.

Answer (score 0):

The word "to radiate" means "to move outward" as in the same root as "radius."  Thus the same word gets used for things that spread out from a point source but are otherwise are very different from one another, such as electromagnetic radiation (light waves) and nuclear radiation (alpha particles).  It is not implying an underlying connection other than the outward motion.